# Pagerfanta template causing error in psalm

Tags: php, pagerfanta, psalm-php

I am trying to move from phpdoc to psalm and I am getting weird error with its template based returns.

```php
class Message {}

interface FooInterface
{
    /** @return Pagerfanta|Message[] */
    public function getMessages(): Pagerfanta;
}
```

This is showing `TooManyTemplateParams` error even though I am setting exactly one and Pagerfanta also has exactly one parameter set in its definition.

Even psalm online validator is showing this error:
https://psalm.dev/r/68b22e896f

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `Pagerfanta` class (as presented in the linked snippet) does indeed have no type parameters - it has 0 `@template` tags.

You need to upgrade to a later version of Pagerfanta that has this issue fixed. 2.7.2 seems to have the fix in place.

Sidenote: `Pagerfanta|Message[]` form is a legacy PHPStorm syntax and I would recommend to avoid it due to ambiguity.